# How do you add .NET MVC controls to umbraco?

Tags: c#, .net, controls, umbraco

How do you add MVC controls to umbraco?

I know in web forms you copy the aspx file into umbraco's usercontrols folder, and the control's dll file into umbraco's bin folder.

But i dont know how to do this for MVC controls.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on what you mean by MVC control. Regardless, in Umbraco, all 'external' interfaces are defined through the Developer > Macros section.

Answer (score 1):

In solution explorer Go to controller Folder and right click on it then add controller and write the code in it you want

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading these to get a handle on how MVC works in Umbraco:

http://shazwazza.com/post/native-mvc-support-in-umbraco-coming-very-soon/

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/10/30/getting-started-with-mvc-in-umbraco-410.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean one of these two:

**1. Child Actions**

Read this: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Mvc/child-actions

It works in the same way as child actions in Mvc, just that your controllers need to be `SurfaceControllers`

**2. Macro Partials**

If what you need is a simple re-usable user controls, then you only need to use partials. You can create a .cshtml file inside Views/MacroPartials then create login to /umbraco and create a Macro that references that partial.

You can the render it with @Umbraco.RenderMacro("myMacro")